# How to add a legend in empty space of base pairs plot in R?

Tags: r

What would be the most straightforward way to add a legend in a plot like this?

```
pairs(
    matrix(rnorm(3 * 100), nrow = 100, ncol = 3),
    col = rep(1:2, 50),
    lower.panel = NULL
)
```

[image: example]

The legend would go where the red circle is or anywhere in the lower triangle of the matrix really

Answer (score 2):

```
par(xpd = NA)

legend("bottomleft", fill = ..., legend = ...)
```